Single SPA - Share Angular standalone component
I have a setup with single spa + 3 Angular apps, one Angular app is called ui-kit and I want to export standalone components to share between the two other apps
// main.single-spa.ts - Ui Kit app

export * from './app/button/button.component';

// app.component - Angular App 1

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import { ButtonComponent } from '@shared/ui-kit';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterOutlet, ButtonComponent],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.scss',
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(ButtonComponent);
  }
}


Here I get the error on the imports array 'imports' must be an array of components, directives, pipes, or NgModules. Value is of type '[RouterOutlet, undefined]'
But trying to log the component in the init gives me a correct Angular component class so I guess it's a problem of types.
Here is my declarations.d.ts
declare module '@shared/ui-kit' {
  import { Type } from '@angular/core';

  export const ButtonComponent: Type<any>;
  export function getData(data: string): string;
}

I tried to have my declarations.d.ts as
declare module '@shared/ui-kit';



How are you distributing the ui-kit? Is it a npm package? If yes, does the final bundle contain TypeScript files or JavaScript files? In case of JavaScript files, how did you build the project?

What you're trying to do has nothing to do with single-spa.  You either follow the guidelines for single-spa parcels, or follow whatever guidelines/tricks/hacks exist to download Angular components from Angular projects.  These are 2 independent and unrelated things, despite going for the same objective.
